# Java - Runtime.getRuntime().exec() Key event

Tags: java, multithreading, events, runtime

There is my problem, i got a .bat who had to do :

```
@echo off
echo "Hello world!"
pause
```

My answer is, is there a way to catch the **event** "Press Any Key" (from an external program)  when the java program use *Runtime.getRuntime().exec(FullCommand)*?

In my java code i use all flux (inputstream, outputstream, errorstream, into separate thread)
and i already tryed to catch the line with a **BufferedReader**, but the "Press Any Key" don't come if i don't use my outputstream to simulate press key **Enter** with *newLine();*, because the process don't want to finish.

So i wanted to know if there is a trick to know when the process wait or if there is a way to catch the inputstream "Press Any Key" before Enter key method, to use outputstream method after (because i don't want to use this method for all scripts that i run).

> 1) `Run Exec`

```
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(FullCommand);
try {
Ti = new Thread(new DisplayInputStream(proc.getInputStream())); 
Te = new Thread(new DisplayDebugStream(proc.getErrorStream()));

Ti.start();
Te.start();

proc.waitFor();
Ti.join();                                                      
Te.join();
}
......
```

> 2) `InputStream` method

```
BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(inputStream);
setInfosProcess(null);
try {
    while ((StrInprocess = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(???) //Condition Press Event key
        {
            Thread To;
            To = new Thread(new DisplayOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream()));
            To.start();
        }
        if (getInfosProcess() == null) {
            setInfosProcess(StrInprocess + "\n");
        } else {
            setInfosProcess(getInfosProcess() + StrInprocess + "\n");
        }
    }
} 
......
```

> 3) `OutputStream` method

```
BufferedWriter bwr = getBufferedWriter(outputStream);
        setOutputProcess(null);

        try { 
            bwr.newLine();// Simulate pressing of the Enter key
            bwr.flush();// Flush the stream, otherwise it doesn't work
        } 
        ......
```

> debug

```
        run:
        Hello world! Test:-1 //To compare string with what i want
        //"Press Any Key" from pause don't come
        //infinite loop caused by **pause**
```

Ty for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read it **character by character** (Or a group of characters at a time) instead of line by line.

```
BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(inputStream);
setInfosProcess(null);
char[] cbuf = new char[1024]; // Adjust the length of the array to suit your needs.
StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try {
    while ((StrInprocess = br.read(cbuf)) != -1) {
         outputBuilder.append(cbuf); // You will get the "Press Any Key" text as soon as it appears.
         // Whatever you want to do here with the outputBuilder object...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,  the problem is that the process wait the press key to continu what he have to do (in that case exit), so the Buffer can't read the "Press Any Key" from pause before i use the output method, and this is really strange.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Still you didn't get the `Press Any Key` text?

Comment: Strange... You probably have a problem somewhere else... I tried the code and the outputBuilder has the text `Press Any Key...` just fine...

Comment: i finally see why that didn't worked for me, i had some [null] and space in the Buffer when i use br.read and outputBuilder, but a part of the sentence was there 'ress Any" so, i just had to fix this and that will be good. Ty for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to listen for a key press
Read about java.awt.event.KeyListener

```
f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key pressed code=" + e.getKeyCode() + ", char=" + e.getKeyChar());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
});
```

Comment: i don't think this is what op is asking

Comment: KeyListener will catch my key pressed, but it's not that i want, i only want to catch the input from the external program who said that i need to press something.